# Cufon selector problems

Tags: css, css-selectors, cufon

I am using Cufon (http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) to replace some text in a menu.

Problem is that I only need to style the first `<li>` of the first `<ul>`.

I have tried using:

```
Cufon.replace('#menu ul li > a', { fontFamily: 'Christopherhand', hover: { color: '#99c635'}});
```

With the `>` seperator, but it does not work. It still replaces the `#menu ul li ul li a`

This is my markup:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="current">
            <a href="#1">About JW</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#2">Subpage 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#3">Subpage 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#4">Subpage 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#5">Subpage 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#2">Our Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#3">Best Recipes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#4">Health &amp; Diet</a></li>
        <li><a href="#5">Our Ads</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Can anyone see the problem? It should work without adding a class to sub `<ul>`. :-)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
Cufon.replace('#menu > ul:first > li:first > a');
```

but you have to include jQuery before cufon import in order to use such selector.

https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/usage

Comment: This fixed it. I used it without li:first - now it works as it should! Thanks :-)